# Can I turn normal speakers into wireless Bluetooth speakers with Bluetooth modules?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wireless, bluetooth, android

I want to turn my simple wired speakers with 8mm audio jack to wireless Bluetooth speakers which can be operated from an android Smartphone with Bluetooth module and microcontroller.

(*Sorry for my English*.)

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: for an answer with more details provide more information

Comment: You need a a2dp bluetooth module. A2DP is the bluetooth audio standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The keywords you are looking for are: "Bluetooth Audio Jack"

With the keywords you can find products on the market ([ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/bluetooth-audio-jack)).

Or even diy examples to build one like [this](http://eleccelerator.com/diy-bluetooth-headphones/).